# Coloring Text within $ - NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

```
pattern = @"(\\$.*?\\$)";
regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:&error];
matches = [regex matchesInString:self options:0 range: searchedRange];
for (NSTextCheckingResult* match in matches) {
    [string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blueColor] range:[match range]];
}
```

I'm using the above code to color text inbetween two dollar signs. So the hello world text in the following string would be colored blue, with the dollar signs removed:

```
@"This won't be blue. $hello world$. This won't be blue";
```

Now, however, I want a single dollar sign to not be colored blue. I only want the pattern to match when the first dollar sign is succeeded by a character in a-zA-Z0-9 and likewise the second dollar sign should be preceded by a character in a-zA-Z0-9. How can I do this?

Comment: can the content between dollar can be of single character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the capturing group a bit after the first `$` and before the last `$`, and use `matchAtIndex:1` to only get Group 1 value:

```
pattern = @"\\$([A-Za-z0-9].*?)(?<=[A-Za-z0-9])\\$";
               ^ ^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And

```
[string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blueColor] range:[match matchAtIndex:1]];
```

Pattern details:

- `\\$` -  a literal `$`
- `([A-Za-z0-9].*?)` - a letter or digit followed with 0+ any chars but a newline as few as possible upto the  first
- `(?<=[A-Za-z0-9])\\$` - `$` that is preceded with a letter or digit

If you only need to make sure a digit or letter appears after the first `$`, use

```
pattern = @"\\$\\b(?!_)(.*?)\\$";
```

Where the first `$` can be followed with letters or digits, but not `_`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to adjust your regular expression a little.

A really good resource for this is http://regexr.com/ because it lets you try out new expressions live.

In this specific case you probably want:

```
pattern = @"(\\$.+\\$)";
```

The difference between * and + is that + requires at least 1 character. Also the ? was not doing anything because the * by default makes something optional.

Comment: but this still allows for space characters

Comment: ah, i missed that bit, you would just need to replace the . with what you specified in the question surrounded with []

Comment: Oh ok perfect. Thanks :)

Comment: this will include `$` in replacement

Comment: @rock321987 sure, but if you wanted to add attribute tags to some text you would probably just use HTML

Comment: Actually, what I really need is to make sure the character just after the dollar sign is not a space. But there could be spaces characters after that...

Comment: @Apollo and can there be spaces before last `$`?

Comment: @rock321987 yes there can.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this does what I want `pattern = @"(\\$[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}.*\\$)";`

Thanks to Tristan for the resource

Comment: you can try using `(?<=\\$)(?=[A-Za-z0-9])[^$]*(?=\\$)`